# new chromedriver: can't send keys to iframe body

Tags: watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Wait-webdriver, chrome-driver

I have the following html code:

```
 <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="0" src="" title="Rich text editor, ctl00_ContentMain_EditSegment1_txtDesc" aria-describedby="cke_27" style="width:100%;height:100%">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html class="CSS1Compat" lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<title data-cke-title="Rich text editor, ctl00_ContentMain_EditSegment1_txtDesc">Rich text editor, ctl00_ContentMain_EditSegment1_txtDesc</title>
<link href="http:somefile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style data-cke-temp="1" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="cke_show_borders" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
<br type="_moz">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I used the following code to set data to the body of the iframe :

```
@browser.frame(:title => 'Rich text editor, ctl00_ContentMain_EditSegment1_txtDesc').send_keys  "description"
```

Yesterday I updated my chromedriver with new one: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list
and this line doesn't work for me anymore, but it still works using old chromedriver

Any ideas how can I make it work with new chromedriver?

Thanks,
Anna

Comment: Can you clarify what "doesn't work for me anymore" means? Is there an exception?

Comment: no exceptions... it just doesn't set data into the iframe body, but it works with old driver. it send the data i wanna see in the iframe body to the previously focused element

Comment: Perhaps try sending keys on the actual element you want to interact with (rather than the frame)?

Comment: but it's strange... it works with old chromedriver.how come?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed in new chromedriver v.2.2:

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

Yes, got the same issue. Switched back to old version and got it to work again.

Got all the frameSwitch code in a C# try/catch and no error is given, just an empty textfield.

( Dojo richtext )

Comment: This in not an answer, it's a comment. When your reputation grows you will be able to post also comment, until there please answer if you have an answer and can explain it. Enjoy the site!